# mongoose query help ~ some kind of distinct and also include $min

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose 4.9.4

This is the data I have

```
[ { _id: 1, Cn: "US", StProv: 'W', enabled: true },
    { _id: 2, Cn: "US", StProv: 'O', enabled: true },
    { _id: 3, Cn: "US", StProv: 'C', enabled: true },
    { _id: 4, Cn: "CA", StProv: 'Q', enabled: true },
    { _id: 5, Cn: "CA", StProv: 'O', enabled: true },
    { _id: 6, Cn: "MX", StProv: 'C', enabled: false },
    { _id: 7, Cn: "MX", StProv: 'S', enabled: false }
]
```

This is the result I need

```
[ { _id: 4, Cn: "CA" },
    { _id: 1, Cn: "US" }
] // note: sorted by Cn
```

I tried to aggregate and return the $min _id, but no luck.
How does this work?  I'm not sure how to even begin this one.

In SQL, crazy easy

```
select min(_id), Cn 
from Model 
where enabled = true
group by Cn
order by Cn
```

Comment: Something like `db.collection.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$Cn", id:{$min:"$_id"}}}, {$sort:{_id:1}})`

Comment: But that is mongodb ~ not mongoosejs.  Otherwise you're right (i think)